# Specifying line length in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

(I apologise if this question has been asked before, it's hard to believe it hasn't, but I can't find any material on it.) I want to draw a line passing through two points where I can specify the width. The line should go from the first given point in the direction of the second point, then continue until the given length is up. I want to be able to type something like `\draw[length=5] (0,0)--(1,2);` to accomplish this.

**Here's what I have so far:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0)--(1,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Again, the problem with this is that it draws a line terminating at the two given points, but I only want it to terminate at one point (the first) but continue until the length specified has been used up at the other end. I know that this can be accomplished by always manually calculating the coordinates using some math, but that is ridiculously tedious and there must be a better way to do it! Thanks in advance.

Comment: see if polar coordinate can be of help. using it you need to determine angle of line (with `atan` function, for example): `\draw (0,0) -- (<angle>:5cm);`

Comment: Is that the best way? It can be a bit tedious especially when one of those points isn't at the origin...

Comment: Why? You could do `\draw (10,20) -- (angle:5cm)`. For the calculation, you can assume the point you start the origin if you want.

Comment: How will I find the angle given any two arbitrary points? Do I need to do something like type it into a calculator?

Comment: @Teyyf, well, you need some basic knowledge from geometry (how calculate angle from given catheterizes of triangle)   :-)

Comment: Yes of course I can do that; but as mentioned if I want to plot many many points, especially if the coordinates of my points aren't nice, then it would quickly become tedious to do so!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you know the angle, then you can use relative polar coodinates, e.g. `\draw (1,1) -- +(30:2cm);`. The `+` before the polar coordinate indicates that the previous coordinate (`(1,1)`) should be used as the origin. If you use `++(30:2cm)`, the current point is also updated, so if you add another relative coordinate to the path, the origin of that will be the end point of the first segment.

If you have two points, you can use the features of the `calc` library. `($(a)!3cm!(b)$)` is the coordinate that is 3cm away from `a`, at the line passing through `a` and `b`. Hence, `\draw (a) -- ($(a)!3cm!(b)$);` draws a line from `a` to that point.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) grid (4,3);

  \node[inner sep=1pt,fill, label=above left:a] (a) at (1,1) {};
  \node[inner sep=1pt,fill, label=above left:b] (b) at (3,2) {};

  \draw [red] (a) -- +(30:2cm);

  \draw [blue] (a) -- ($(a)!3cm!(b)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```